# Why is Samba exporting php files as directories

Tags: php, directory, export, samba

I recently rebuilt my Ubuntu server after boot disk problems.
There are several other physical disks on the server.

Now, when Samba exports **some** php files, from one of the other disks, those files are seen both by Windows and another Ubuntu machine as folders. Other files in the same exported folder show correctly as files.

Note that in the attachment, index.php shows as a folder (which is inaccessible) while swapdblocations.php shows correctly as a file.

Curiously, if I copy index.php to index_01.php, it shows up as a file as it should.  This confirms that the file permissions are correct (and they are the same as swapdb.php).

And since some php files are exported properly, I assume the the Samba configuration file is set up correctly.

I am completely stumped.  Suggestions?

[image: Viewl Of Windows directory]

Comment: On further examination, it is not just .php files but also .html and .js files.  Again, not all of these files, just seemingly random ones.

Comment: Although the problem is with web files, you will probably have a better chance of getting an answer over at [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) or the [Unix & Linux group](https://unix.stackexchange.com/). Also, there is a [related ticket](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1801442) out there that sounds similar to this.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I've tried Serverfault  and Ubuntu forums with no responses. The related ticket references CIFS, not SMB.